# How to attach a module to a drupal article?

Tags: php, web, drupal

I have a php function in a drupal module. This function outputs some random text. I want to attach this module to a Drupal article so that each time someone creates an article, random text will appear in it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to use a Drupal hook function to modify the content of the node.

Assuming your module is called "my_module":, you'd add another function to your my_module.module file as follows:

```
function my_module_node_view(&$node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    // We want to make sure this only applies to nodes of the content type "article"
    if ($node->type == "article") { 
        // Append the output of your function to the body; this could easily be added to any other field as well
        $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $node->body['und'][0]['value'] . my_module_random_text_function();
    }
}
```

Note: the $node object is automatically passed to this hook function by reference, so you don't need to worry about returning anything from the function.

If you wanted to apply this at the theme layer, you could use the theme_preprocess_node hook in your theme's template.php file, but your original question suggested that you'd already gone down the plugin route.